# What should I edit so that my total will add all the possible variable ($order_stotal)

Tags: php, sql, addition

How about this? This is at the top of my codes but i think this is helpless. Every time the third order comes in the calculation is all wrong.

```
<?php
include("dbconnection.php");

if ($_SESSION["loggedin"] != "true") 
header("Location:memberlogin.php");

$cust_id = $_SESSION["cust_id"];
```

Selecting all from the database

```
$result = mysql_query("select customer.*, product.*, order_details.* from customer, product,  order_details where customer.cust_id=$cust_id and product.pro_id=product.pro_id and order_details.order_details_id = order_details.order_details_id")or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
?>
    <?php
        $x=1;

        $bill_total=5.00;
        $order_stotal=$row["order_stotal"];
        $result = mysql_query("select product.*,order_details.* from product,order_details 
        where order_details.pro_id= product.pro_id ");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

        {
        ?>
```

I need it to echo all the possible subtotal. I think i just need to edit this or something i'm not quite sure

```
        <?php 
        $x++;
        $bill_total +=$order_stotal;
        } 
        ?>
                RM &nbsp
                <?php

                echo number_format($bill_total,2);
                ?>
```

Then this one here is the function of the button

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["submitbtn"]))
{
$bill_id=rand(1000,9999);
$bill_date=date("Y-m-d"); 
$bill_state=$_POST["bill_state"];
$bill_city=$_POST["bill_city"];
$bill_add=$_POST["bill_add"];
$bill_post=$_POST["bill_post"];

mysql_query("insert into bill
(cust_id, bill_date, bill_total, bill_state, bill_city, bill_add, 
bill_post)
 values('$cust_id','$bill_date', 
'$bill_total', '$bill_state', '$bill_city','$bill_add','$bill_post')")or die(mysql_error());

}

?>
```

Comment: How come you have `$row['order_total']` before the loop and inside the loop? I'm confused...

Comment: You have to paste whole codes for helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bill_total +=$row['order_stotal'];
```

This should work for combining all the values from that line in the rows retrieved by the database.

(You also need to remove the reference to $row['order_stotal'] from before the query, unless you're using a different query from another part of the script to set it.)

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot for your help it settles it